# Log the API call in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api

I am trying to log the api call like the attached picture[image: Required Output] how to do it with node? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExpressJS

MorganJS is a popular option for logging incoming HTTP traffics

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

And if you need your logs to format to the same as the attachment u showed:

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-format-string-of-predefined-tokens